# How can I add back the faint vertical line that shows the corresponding html

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzEbq.png)
How can I get back the faint vertical line that shows the corresponding html tags?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eErGu.jpg)
Notice how the html, body, and head tags all have faint vertical lines?

I could not find any guide that solves this.

Comment: Enable the `Editor > Guides: Indentation` setting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.